# Why is the reputation notification adding like this?

Tags: support, reputation, achievements-dialog, notification-bar

The attached image is self explanatory. 74 is not the sum I can add by the given notifications.

[image: Screenshot with +5, +5, +2, and +100]

Comment: One or more of your posts, having upvotes, was deleted, resulting in reputation loss which is not shown in the achievements dialog. You can see the deleted posts in the "deleted recent answers" link in your [Answers tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=answers). (assuming it's on SO.)